# Using the Minus statement to return result set

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using **Oracle SQL Developer**, I need to compare 2 tables and return the result set. The queries are tricky on this one, and I have not been able to come across an example that is similar to what I am trying to accomplish.

I have attempted to create the query below but am not sure how to move forward, as the queries have different number of result columns. **Some of the columns are similar but not exact**, and I still want the result set to display the records from the first query, as I am just using the second query to make sure there are no duplicates in the table.

I essentially will be asking the user for a number, in this case 15, the first query will return a result set, say of 20 records, I then need to use ORDER from the first query to check in the second query and then return all the records that appeared in the first set but not in the second.

```
SELECT MODEL, ORDR, CONSMR, PRODN 
FROM a.Store // db schema
WHERE (MODEL = '15') // No problems on this query

MINUS

SELECT MODEL, ORDR 
FROM newStore 
WHERE ORDR..... // Not sure what should go here
```

Comment: The columns in the two queries for a `MINUS` must have the same number of columns they must have compatible types (the same rules as for `UNION`. You can also not have a column named `ORDER` because that is a reserved word. You have to quote it `"ORDER"` if you really want to use it as a column name.

Comment: Thanks for your response, essentially I am only using the second query to ensure none of the records from the first query are there, so I really don't need the columns to be the same. I am looking more into`NOT EXISTS`

Comment: Yes you **do** need the columns to be the same, otherwise you cannot use `MINUS`

Comment: Which is why I am looking into `NOT EXIST` because the columns cannot and will not be the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a NOT EXISTS.  Basically, here's the format:

```
SELECT <stuff> FROM Table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM Table2
   WHERE Table1.Something = Table2.Something)
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer @JoshEdwards ! `SELECT MODEL, ORDER, CONSMR, PRODN FROM a.Store WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ORDER FROM newStore WHERE a.Store.ORDER = newStore. ORDER);` works perfectly! However, being that I will be requesting a value from a user I need to incorporate the **WHERE (MODEL = '2015')** to the first query in order to pull the correct result set. When I keep that addition where clause, I receive a syntax error for a partially recognized rule stating: `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended 00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"`

Comment: Can you post what you're trying here?  It should be simple -  SELECT <stuff> FROM Table1 WHERE MODEL = '2015' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.Something = Table2.Something)

Comment: **Attempt 1:** 
  `SELECT MODEL, ORDR, CONSMR, PRODN 
    FROM a.Store 
    WHERE (MODEL = ‘2015’)
     (WHERE NOT EXISTS 
     (SELECT ORDR FROM newStore WHERE a.Store.ORDR = newStore. ORDR))`
**Result:** Syntax Error; `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended 00933. 00000 - "SQL command not properly ended".`


**Attempt 2:**
`SELECT MODEL, ORDR, CONSMR, PRODN 
    FROM a.Store 
    WHERE (MODEL = ‘2015’)
     (AND NOT EXISTS 
     (SELECT ORDR FROM newStore WHERE a.Store.ORDR = newStore. ORDR))`
**Result:** same number of records as query #1 if it were run alone

Comment: Try this:   SELECT MODEL, ORDR, CONSMR, PRODN FROM Store as a WHERE MODEL = ‘2015’ AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ORDR FROM newStore as b WHERE a.Store.ORDR = b.ORDR AND a.MODEL <> b.MODEL)   You can, of course, adjust the not equals to use whatever field you want.  However, if you don't specify that, then your NOT EXISTS will eliminate all records, because you'd basically be saying give me everything in a table where the row I want doesn't actually exist.